# pushing into stack from function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, stack, push

In my testfunction, I'm trying to push two values into my stack. It works well from main(), but I think when using the testfunc() I messed up with the pointers?

The values reach the push() function, but the values doesn't end up in my stack at all.

Thanks in advance for help

```
struct StackNode
    {
        unsigned int data;
        struct StackNode* next;
    };

    struct StackNode* newNode(unsigned int data)
    {
        struct StackNode* stackNode =
                  (struct StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
        stackNode->data = data;
        stackNode->next = NULL;

        return stackNode;
    }

    int isEmpty(struct StackNode *root)
    {
        return !root;
    }

    void push(struct StackNode** root, unsigned int data)
    {
        struct StackNode* stackNode = newNode(data);
        stackNode->next = *root;
        *root = stackNode;
        printf("%u pushed to stack\n", data);
    }

    void pop(struct StackNode** root)
    {
        if (isEmpty(*root))
            printf("ERROR");
        struct StackNode* temp = *root;
        *root = (*root)->next;
        free(temp);

    }

    unsigned int peek(struct StackNode* root)
    {
        if (isEmpty(root))
            return -2;
        return root->data;
    }
void testfunc(struct StackNode* root, unsigned int a, unsigned int b) 
{
       struct StackNode *r=root;
       push(&r, a);
       push(&r, b); 
    }
```

Main

```
int main()
    {
        struct StackNode* root = NULL;
        push(&root,0); // Works well and pushes "0" to the stack.

        testfunc(root,12,15); // <-- doesn't push any value in the stack
}
```

Comment: Simply put: never use pointer-to-pointer unless you intend to return a pointer through that parameter. And there's no real reason why you need to pass around `StackNode**`. It would be better if you put all allocation and hardcopies inside the stack ADT and not expose any internals at all to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `push` function modifies the root :

```
*root = stackNode;
```

In your `testfunc`, this change is done to the `root` variable which is local to the function. Ie. any change to it will not be visible in the calling function (`main`). So, from the point of view of `main`, it's as if nothing changed, since the `root` variable there hasn't changed.

To make sure that a change to `root` in `testfunc` is also visible in `main`, you can eg. return it :

```
struct StackNode* testfunc(struct StackNode* root, unsigned int a, unsigned int b) 
{
   push(&root, a);
   push(&root, b);
   return root;
}

root = testfunc(root, 12, 15);
```

Or alternatively, you can :

```
void testfunc(struct StackNode** root, unsigned int a, unsigned int b) 
{
   push(root, a);
   push(root, b);
}

testfunc(&root, 12, 15);
```

Comment: Sander is correct. A side.. I would also point out that your `peek` function is returning a negative to an `unsigned int`.. your compiler should be warning about this.

Comment: thanks a lot, got it working with your suggestions. anyways i might get rid of pointer-to-pointer at all as what Lundin wrote.. edit: oh and thanks dutchRooster, I'm aware of that :)